# Understanding Modular Multiplication

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm reading a book on Cryptography and in the book it explains:

> A modular multiplication is quite natural to define over such a set of
> numbers. Let’s take the following multiplication, for example:
>
> 3 x 2 = 6
>
> With what you learned above, you know that 6 is congruent to 1 modulo
> 5, and thus the equation can be rewritten as
>
> 3 x 2 = 1 mod 5
>
> Quite straightforward isn’t it? Note that the previous equation tells
> us that 3 is the inverse of 2, and vice versa. So we can also write,
> for example:
>
> 3^-1 = 2 mod 5

I can understand that 3 x 2 = 6.

And 6 mod 5 = 1 or 6  % 5 == 1.  Therefore 3x2 = 1 mod 5

However what I don't understand is how it suddenly become proof that:
3^-1 = 2 mod 5

I understand that 3^-1 = 1/3....
so if
3^-1 = 2 mod 5

then

1/3 = 2 mod 5
no?  I'm getting confused....

What foundational knowledge do I need to understand and how to connect the dots????

Thank you.

Comment: In beginning abstract algebra, one learns that $aa^{-1}=1$, where $1$ is the identity element

Comment: You need to stop thinking in terms of remainders and learn about congruences. Many resources linked to [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n).

Comment: I understand that 3^-1 = 1/3.... so if 3^-1 = 2 mod 5

then

1/3 = 2 mod 5 no? I'm getting confused....

Comment: $a^{-1}=b$ simply means that with respect to the multiplication in question we have $a\cdot b=1$. You can then use it to solve linear equations just like in junior high. Given the congruence
$$3x\equiv4\pmod5$$
you solve it by multiplying it with $3^{-1}$ just like you would solve the equation $3x=4$. Only this time $3^{-1}=2$, so
$$x\equiv3^{-1}\cdot3x\equiv3^{-1}\cdot4=2\cdot4=8\equiv3.$$
And you can verify that this is a solution as $3\cdot3=9\equiv4$.

Comment: $2^{-1} =3 \mod 5$

Comment: May be the mental block you have is thinking that $3^{-1}$ has a meaning that does not depend on the context? In the reals or rationals $3^{-1}$ is, indeed $\dfrac13$. In $\Bbb{Z}_5$ it means $2$. In $\Bbb{Z}_{10}$ it means $7$. Whatever you can have in place of $x$ such that $3x=1$ is true. The meaning of the product in $3\cdot x$ depends on the context so the meaning of $3^{-1}$ will then change accordingly.

Comment: if 3x2 = 1 mod 5 then 6 mod 5 = 1 so 6/3 mod 5 = 1 / 3 which is another representation of 2 mod 5 = 3 ^-1. ......correct?

Comment: Correct, cause $6 \cdot 3^{-1}=6 \cdot 2 =12 \equiv 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: holds $(5k+\color{red}{2})(5l+\color{red}{3})=5n+\color{red}{1}$.